$ (2) \subset R$ is not a product of prime ideals in $ R = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}] $
Consider the ideal $ I = (2, 1 + \sqrt{-19}) $ inside the ring $ R = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}] $.
Show that $ I \cdot I^{-1} \neq R $ and $ I^2 = 2I $.Use this to show that $ (2) \subset R$ is not a product of prime ideals.
My try:
$
I^2 = (2, 1 + \sqrt{-19}) \cdot (2, 1 + \sqrt{-19})=(2 \cdot 2, 2 \cdot (1 + \sqrt{-19}), (1 + \sqrt{-19}) \cdot 2, (1 + \sqrt{-19}) \cdot (1 + \sqrt{-19}))
= (4, 2 + 2\sqrt{-19}, 2 + 2\sqrt{-19}, (1 + \sqrt{-19})^2)
$
Since
$(1 + \sqrt{-19})^2 = 1 + 2\sqrt{-19} + (\sqrt{-19})^2 = 1 + 2\sqrt{-19} - 19 = -18 + 2\sqrt{-19}$
we have:
$I^2 = (4, 2 + 2\sqrt{-19}, -18 + 2\sqrt{-19})=2 \cdot (2, 1 + \sqrt{-19})$
Thus $I^2 = 2I$
Suppose $ I $ were invertible, then $ I \cdot I^{-1} = R $. Then $(2)=2R=2II^{-1}=I^2I^{-1}=I$ is a contradiction since $ 1 +\sqrt{-19}\in I$ but $ \notin (2)$. So I is not invertible ,i.e  $ I \cdot I^{-1} \neq R $
Now I am having trouble proving that $ (2) $ Is Not a Product of Prime Ideals
Suppose by sake of contradiction that the contrary holds, so $(2)=\prod_{i=1}^nP_i$, with the $P_i$' s prime ideals, but I don't know how to finish. How would it go?

If $(2)=\prod P_i$, then in particular $2\in P_i$. How many such prime ideals are there in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-19}]$?

@anankElpis. Could you give more details? My knowledge of ideals is very basic. I have no idea how to address your question

Claim: The only prime ideal $\mathfrak p\subseteq\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-19}]$ such  that $(2)\subseteq\mathfrak p$ is $\mathfrak p=(2,1+\sqrt{-19})$.
Proof: Since $$(1+\sqrt{-19})(1-\sqrt{-19})=20\in(2)\subseteq\mathfrak p,$$ we know that $1+\sqrt{-19}\in\mathfrak p$ or $1-\sqrt{-19}\in\mathfrak p$. Since those two elements sum to $2\in\mathfrak p$, they are actually both contained in $\mathfrak p$. Therefore, we have $(2,1+\sqrt{-19})\subseteq\mathfrak p$. To conclude, it suffices to show that $(2,1+\sqrt{-19})$ is maximal. We compute the quotient: \begin{align}\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-19}]/(2,1+{\sqrt{-19}})&\cong\mathbb Z[X]/(2,X+1,X^2+19)\\&\cong \mathbb F_2[X]/(X+1,(X+1)^2)\\&=\mathbb F_2[X]/(X+1)\cong\mathbb F_2\end{align} which is a field as required.

Now we can tackle the question: Assume that $(2)=\prod_{i=1}^n\mathfrak p_i$ is a product of prime ideals. Since $\prod_{i=1}^n\mathfrak p_i\subset\mathfrak p_i$ for each $i$, we conclude $\mathfrak p_i=(2,1+\sqrt{-19})$ by the claim. Therefore, the only possibility is that $(2)=(2,1+\sqrt{-19})^k$ for some $k\geq1$. Clearly $k=1$ doesn't work, and for $k\geq2$ you've already shown that $$(2,1+\sqrt{-19})^k\subseteq (2,1+\sqrt{-19})^2=(2)(2,1+\sqrt{-19})\subsetneq (2).$$ This gives the desired contradiction.

Why is $ (2)(2,1+\sqrt{-19})\subsetneq (2)$ and how is $(2,1+\sqrt{-19})^k \subsetneq (2)$ a contradiction?

I guess you meant $2(2,1+\sqrt{19})$ instead of  $(2)(2,1+\sqrt{19})$ Still what would be an element in  $2(2,1+\sqrt{19})$ that is not in ? I can't find any. Every element in  $2(2,1+\sqrt{19})$  is a divisible by 2 so it is  included in $(2)$. then $(2) = (2,1+\sqrt{19})^k \subseteq (2)$ which is no contradiction

*....that is not in (2)

I think the argument should be fixed like this: $(2)=I^k$ implies using $I^2=2I $that $ (2)=2^k$ I for $k \ge 2$ and clearly $2$ is in $(2)$ but not in $2^k (2,1+\sqrt{-19})$. So this is the contradiction, the argument with the inclusion yields no contradiction Makes sense? Correct me if I am wrong.

Your argument also works, but mine isn't wrong: $(2)(2,1+\sqrt{-19})$ is a strict subset of $(2)$ because $2\in(2)$ but $2\notin(2)(2,1+\sqrt{-19})$, and $(2,1+\sqrt{-19})^k\subsetneq(2)$ is a contradiction because we assumed $(2,1+\sqrt{-19})^k=(2)$, so this becomes $(2)\subsetneq (2)$, which is clearly wrong.
